# How to put a constraint on weights of assets in a portfolio when using portopt function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, portfolio

I am trying to optimize a portfolio with 10 assets and those can be grouped into five. Say asset one and two is in group 1.
Now in my optimization, I need the weights of group assets to be equal. 
For example, Asset 1 and Asset 2 is in group 1. So I need weights of asset 1 and asset 2 to be equal in the possible optimized portfolio.
How do I include this constraint into portopt function?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group them prior to optimization.

For example, if a group `k` consists of `x,y,z`, and you wish them to have the same weight, then just set this weight. Create synthetic: `k = 1/3 * (x + y + z)`. Then optimize the groups, not the assets.

Comment: Thank you Serg. I tried it like this ---> Say -W1+W2=<0 and W1-W2=<0, then the asset allocations were equal. However it is better to optimize the groups like you said it seems. Anyway thanks for the kind help. Cheers.

Comment: @Kanch If this answer was helpful for you I would recommend you to accept it.